# How to create a sharedDrive in google api (node.js)

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

How do you make a shared drive from the google drive api, the code in the documentation doesnt work in the line

```
driveService.drives.create({...
```

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-shareddrives

Answer (score 0):

### The code snippet you provide is based on the previous creation of `driveService`

- To create `driveService`, you need to follow the flow as described in the [Drive API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java)
- The only difference is that the quickstart calls the variable to which the `new Drive.Builder` is assigned `Drive service`, while in the sample for [creating shared drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-shareddrives) is is called `driveService` instead of `service`
- All you need to do is to patch the two code pieces together in a way that you use both times the same variable name

Sample:

```java
// follow the quickstart
...
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
//now create the shared drive
Drive driveMetadata = new Drive();
driveMetadata.setName("Project Resources");
String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
Drive drive = service.drives().create(requestId,
    driveMetadata)
    .execute();
System.out.println("Drive ID: " + drive.getId());
...
```

Comment: Is this correct? I came here with the same doubt. I am using "com.google.api.services.drive.Drive" and there is no constructor without parameter and no function "drives().create()".

Comment: @marcellorvalle: See the sample https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-shareddrives#create_shared_drives